How do I get my button to conditionally render Add to cart state and the quantity state?
I have been attempting creating a shopping cart with product list from https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/product-list-with-cart-5MmqLVAp_d I am currently trying to use redux as I would like to get comfortable with redux toolkit. I am struggling with getting my addToCart to properly conditionally render the two states the button can be in see below:
I tried using a bit of a switch statement but nothing works as it does not render the other sstate and simply only renders the false state I am unsure of how to move forward please help!
I would like the button when pushed to display the quantity state where it shows the increment button and decrement button with the quantity of that specific item.
addToCart component:
import addToCartImg from "../assets/images/icon-add-to-cart.svg";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addItem } from "../features/AddToCartFeature/AddToCartSlice";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { selectItems } from "../features/AddToCartFeature/AddToCartSlice";
import increaseButton from "../assets/images/icon-increment-quantity.svg";
import decreaseButton from "../assets/images/icon-decrement-quantity.svg";

const AddToCart = ({ item }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const itemsInCart = useSelector(selectItems);

    const handleAddToCart = () => {
        const itemId = uuidv4();

        console.log(dispatch(
            addItem({
                ...item,
                id: itemId,
            })
        ));
    };

    // Check if the current item is in the cart
    const isInCart = itemsInCart.some(
        (cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id
    );
    const quantity =
        itemsInCart.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id)
            ?.quantity || 0;

    return (
        <div className=" flex items-center justify-center ">
            {isInCart ? (
                <div className="bg-red rounded-full w-44 absolute bottom-[100px] p-2 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <img
                        src={decreaseButton}
                        alt="decrement button"
                        className="border border-white p-1 rounded-full w-5 h-5"
                    />
                    <p className="mx-[59px]">
                        {quantity}
                    </p>
                    <img
                        src={increaseButton}
                        alt="increment button"
                        className="border border-white p-1 rounded-full"
                    />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <button
                    className="group flex items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-rose-400 p-2 w-44 absolute bottom-[100px] z-10 bg-white text-center hover:border-red hover:text-red"
                    onClick={handleAddToCart}
                >
                    <img
                        src={addToCartImg}
                        alt="add to cart"
                        className="mr-2"
                    />
                    <p className="font-semibold text-rose-900 group-hover:text-red">
                        Add to Cart
                    </p>
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddToCart;


AddToCartSlice.jsx
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    numberOfItems: 0,
    items: [],
};

const addToCartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "addToCart",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addItem: (state, action) => {
            const existingItem = state.items.find(
                (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
            );
            if (existingItem) {
                existingItem.quantity += 1; // Increment quantity
            } else {
                state.items.push({
                    ...action.payload,
                    quantity: 1,
                }); // Add new item with quantity 1
            }
            state.numberOfItems++;
        },
        removeItem: (state, action) => {
            const item = state.items.find(
                (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
            );
            if (item) {
                if (item.quantity > 1) {
                    item.quantity -= 1; // Decrement quantity if more than 1
                } else {
                    state.items = state.items.filter(
                        (item) =>
                            item.id !==
                            action.payload.id
                    ); // Remove item if quantity is 0
                }
            }
            state.numberOfItems--;
        },
    },
});

export const selectItems = (state) => state.addToCart.items;
export const { addItem, removeItem } = addToCartSlice.actions;
export default addToCartSlice.reducer;


item.jsx
import data from "../../data.json";
import AddToCart from "./AddToCart"

const Item = () => {
    return (
        <div className=" lg:col-span-2 md:col-span-2">
            <h1 className="mb-6 text-[2.6rem] font-bold text-rose-900">Desserts</h1>
            <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-rows-3 xl:gap-5 ">
                {data.map((item, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className=" grid relative">
                        <img
                            src={
                                item.image
                                    .thumbnail
                            }
                            alt={item.name}
                            srcSet={`
                            ${item.image.mobile} 640w,
                                    ${item.image.tablet} 768w,
                                    ${item.image.desktop} 1024w
                        `}
                            sizes=" 100vw,
                                        50vw,
                                       33vw"
                               className="mb-10 rounded-lg"
                        />
                        <AddToCart item={ item }/>
                        <p className="text-rose-500">
                            {item.category}
                        </p>
                        <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold text-rose-900">
                            {item.name}
                        </h3>
                        <p className="text-lg font-semibold text-red">
                            ${item.price.toFixed(2)}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Item;



Please explain the two states you want the button to be in and what possible issue you are encountering.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The items in the cart don't have ids until they are added, so the cartItem.id === item.id conditions always evaluate false because item doesn't have a id property, or is a different value because you generate a new id when adding to the cart with addItem({ ...item, id: uuidV4(), }). isInCart is never true.
You probably want your data to have intrinsic id values. Update your data.json file to include id values by default.
data.json
[
  ...,
  {
    "id": 7, // <-- Add a static and unique id property
    "name": "....",
    "category": "....",
    "image: { .... },
    "price": 13.37,
    ...,
  },
  ...
]

Update the code to use the id property when available:
Item.jsx

Use the item.id as the mapped React key instead of the array index.

import data from "../../data.json";
import AddToCart from "./AddToCart"

const Item = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" lg:col-span-2 md:col-span-2">
      <h1 className="mb-6 text-[2.6rem] font-bold text-rose-900">Desserts</h1>
      <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-rows-3 xl:gap-5 ">
        {data.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id} className=" grid relative">
            <img
              src={item.image.thumbnail}
              alt={item.name}
              srcSet={`
                ${item.image.mobile} 640w,
                ${item.image.tablet} 768w,
                ${item.image.desktop} 1024w
              `}
              sizes=" 100vw, 50vw,33vw"
              className="mb-10 rounded-lg"
            />
            <AddToCart item={item} />
            <p className="text-rose-500">
              {item.category}
            </p>
            <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold text-rose-900">
              {item.name}
            </h3>
            <p className="text-lg font-semibold text-red">
              ${item.price.toFixed(2)}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;

AddToCart.jsx

The item now already has an intrinsic id value, so it can be dispatched directly
The comparisons should work as expected

const AddToCart = ({ item }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const itemsInCart = useSelector(selectItems);

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    dispatch(addItem(item));
  };

  // Check if the current item is in the cart
  // Returns found item or undefined
  const itemInCart = itemsInCart.find(
    (cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id
  );

  return (
    <div className=" flex items-center justify-center ">
      {itemInCart ? (
        <div className="bg-red rounded-full w-44 absolute bottom-[100px] p-2 flex items-center justify-center">
          <img
            src={decreaseButton}
            alt="decrement button"
            className="border border-white p-1 rounded-full w-5 h-5"
          />
          <p className="mx-[59px]">
            {itemInCart.quantity}
          </p>
          <img
            src={increaseButton}
            alt="increment button"
            className="border border-white p-1 rounded-full"
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button
          className="group flex items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-rose-400 p-2 w-44 absolute bottom-[100px] z-10 bg-white text-center hover:border-red hover:text-red"
          onClick={handleAddToCart}
        >
          <img
            src={addToCartImg}
            alt="add to cart"
            className="mr-2"
          />
          <p className="font-semibold text-rose-900 group-hover:text-red">
            Add to Cart
          </p>
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddToCart;


Thanks a bunch I was hoping to not have to change the json data but it can't be helped thanks!

@ChrisKola99 If you don't want to modify the data, then an alternative could be to import the data into the app, once somewhere, and map it new references that then include generated ids, i.e. something like import data from "../../data.json"; export const dataWithIds = data.map(item => ({ ...item, id: uuidV4() }));, and use dataWithIds throughout the app. Or you could write a script to process data.json and just inject generated ids, then you only need to ensure new data also has ids when it's updated in the future.
